# Share a folder on android

Tags: file-management, lan

How to share a folder on android so the folder becomes available over LAN to anyone?

No "server" or any complicated "solution"

Just share the folder on android and see it on the computer, as its easily done on windows

Something my grandmother could easily use

Thank you ahead

Comment: Very difficult to almost impossible if I have a folder with many subfolders and many files. Plus, it requires knowing the IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FTP servers. It is available on [Solid Explorer](https://solid-explorer-file-manager.en.uptodown.com/android)

Comment: Yeah, just install and tap Start under left-pane -> FTP Server. That's it.

Comment: Best answer so far. ES File explorer also has this feature. As an option, I've disabled Turn Off on Exit